# New height is not accounted for when using scrollTop after reloading a div within a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap-based modal that allows users to add and view posts:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="prodCommentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="modal-title">Comments</div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" data-no-turbolink>
        <span id="modal-body-span">
          <%= render partial: 'posts/getposts' %>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
          <div class="field" id="post-box">
            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Write a post..." %>
          </div>
          <div class="post-submit">
            <%= f.submit "Post", id: "post_button", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to leave the modal open when a new post is added, I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('/posts',
            $('#new_post').serialize(),
            function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('.modal-body').load(document.URL+' #modal-body-span');
                $('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').prop("scrollHeight"));
                $('#post_content').val('');
            });
    });
});
```

The modal is done in chat style where the newest posts get added to the bottom.  I've got separate javascript which automatically scrolls the modal-body area to the bottom when the modal is first opened.  But what I can't get to work is the scroll to bottom after a new post is submitted (while the modal is still open).  I've observed a few things:

- If I print $('.modal-body').prop("scrollHeight") before and after the load, the value is unchanged.
- If I scroll the posts up and then instead use a large value, like $('.modal-body').scrollTop(10000), it scrolls down after submitting, but to the bottom of the previous post.

It seems that scrollheight gets updated later and until it is, scrollTop will only scroll at most to the old value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many, many tries, finally found something that works (ajaxComplete event). I also needed to solve the problem where new posts may have been added since the last time the page/modal was reloaded and I wanted the latest and greatest content in the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('/posts',
            $('#new_post').serialize(),
            function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('.modal-body').load(document.URL+' #modal-body-span');
                $('#post_content').val('');
            });
    });

    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').load(document.URL+' #modal-body-span');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').prop("scrollHeight"));
    });

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs,modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').prop("scrollHeight"));
    });
});
```

If better or more elegant solutions are out there, still would love to hear them.