# Removing focus state from a stuck button in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Following on to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297754/new-height-is-not-accounted-for-when-using-scrolltop-after-reloading-a-div-withi/24317053#24317053) question.

After I submit my new post, the submit button is getting stuck in the focus state (I've confirmed it if focus and not active by setting them to different background-colors).  Since I need to manually clear the content box, I assume that I need to remove the focus class as well by doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('/posts',
            $('#new_post').serialize(),
            function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('.modal-body').load(document.URL + ' #modal-body-span');
                $('#post_content').val('');
                $('#post_button').removeClass("btn:focus");
            });
});
```

After searching around, I also tried this:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
$('#post_button').removeClass("btn:focus");
```

When that didn't work, I wanted to make sure I have the right element, so I tried this:

```
$('.btn:focus').removeClass("btn:focus");
```

I tried putting the same calls into the ajaxComplete event instead, but that too did not work.

I then forced the element state to :focus via the Chrome inspector and am seeing this:

```
> $('.btn:focus')
[<input class=​"btn btn-primary" id=​"post_button" name=​"commit" type=​"submit" value=​"Post">​]
```

That probably explains why I can't remove the class if it's not really there, but would love an explanation of why and an actual solution?

Comment: I don't think focus is a class, its just a state of a control. Have you tried to simply put the focus on anything else?

Comment: Have you considered `$('.btn:focus').blur()`? *focus* is a [*pseudo–class*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

Comment: Ah, pseudo-class, thanks for the info on that. blur() works perfectly, thanks!